# If a prime ideal has no zero divisors then the ring also has no zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$ such that $P$ has no (non-zero) zero divisors. Prove that $R$ has no (non-zero) zero divisors.

My try:

Let $ab=0$ where $a,b\in R$ .Let us assume that $a\neq 0$ then we prove that $b=0$. Assume that $b \neq 0$.

Now $ab=0\in P$ then either $a\in P $ or $b\in P$ .Now both $a,b$ can't be in $P$ as then $P$ would have zero divisors.

Suppose that $a\notin P$ then $b\in P$.

But how to arrive at a contradiction from here?

Comment: @user26857; The question says that $P$ has no zero divisors that means there exits no $a,b\in P$ such that both are non zero but $ab=0$ ,right?please mention if wrong

Comment: Yes, your interpretation of the question is definitely wrong.

Comment: please give the proper interpretation @user26857

Comment: Just read my comments under the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Claim:** Ring $R$ is an integral domain.

**Proof:** Suppose $a,b\in R$ with $ab=0$, we must show that $a=0$ or $b=0$. Certainly the images $\overline a,\overline b$ of $a,b$ in $A/P$ satisfy $\overline a\overline b=0$, and since $R/P$ is an integral domain (by the definition of prime ideal) one of $\overline a,\overline b$ is zero, that is $a\in P$ or $b\in P$. Assuming by symmetry the former is the case, then either $b=0$ (in which case we are done), or else $b\neq0$ and the fact that $P$ does not contain zero divisors (of $R$) imply that $a=0$

One more "similar" kind of exercise  from Atiyah Macdonald (If you need  hint to solve this please let me know):

> > In a ring $A$, let $\Sigma$ be the set of all ideals in which every element is a zero-divisor. Show that set $\Sigma$ has maximal elements and that every maximal element of $\Sigma$ is a prime ideal. Hence the set of zero-divisors in $A$ is a union of prime ideals.

Comment: The question says that $P$ has no zero divisors that means there exits no $a,b\in P$ such that both are non zero but $ab=0$ ,right?

Comment: Yes,In other words see my first line.

Comment: @ArpitKansal Please don't confuse the OP (and yourself). An ideal $I$ contains (non-zero) zero-divisors iff there is a (non-zero) zero divisor in it, not if there is $a\ne0$ and $b\ne 0$ in $I$ such that $ab=0$.

Comment: @user26857 Ah,I see.But I think my solution is correct?

Comment: @user26857 But I've shown that $R$ does not any zero divisor,right?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is good, but you miss a premise: suppose $a$ is a zero divisor in $R$; then $a\ne0$ and there is $b\ne0$ such that $ab=0$.

Since $0\in P$, either $a\in P$ or $b\in P$, because $P$ is a prime ideal.

Now $a\notin P$, because it's a zero divisor and none belongs to $P$. So $b\in P$; but $b$ is also a zero divisor: contradiction.

Comment: Reposting a part of the OP's answer is not the best choice. I think a more useful answer would have been one clearing the OP's false believe that an ideal $I$ contains (non-zero) zero divisors iff there are non-zero elements $a,b\in I$ such that $ab=0$.

Comment: @user26857 I don't fully understand the objection. But I'll add a note.

Comment: Then maybe you should read more carefully the OP's answer to the question, and possibly my comments around.

Comment: @user26857 I made the proof by contradiction, which seems to be more along the OP's request.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean by zero divisors in $P$ that for both non zero $x \in P$ and $y \in R$ s.t $xy=0$ then, From your try let $b \in P$ then consider $<b> \subseteq P$ then $ab=0$ in $P$ contradiction.

Otherwise if you say that there are no non-zero $x,y \in P$ s.t. $xy=0$ then the statement is false: take $\Bbb Z_{15}$, and $P=<3>$. Then $P$ is a prime ideal which does not contain $x,y\ne0$ such that $xy=0$, but $\Bbb Z_{15}$ has zero divisors.

Comment: I see it now: in some poorly explained way you want to show the OP that he can't find non-zero $a,b\in P$ such that $ab=0$. Then please don't say that $<3>$ does not contain zero divisors. You actually mean that there are no non-zero $a,b\in <3>$ such that $ab=0$.

Comment: May be poorly. If you think you can improve you can edit it. I shall apreciate that. I have written it in my way.